# Scenekit black circle artifacts

Tags: ios, scenekit, artifacts

[image: Scenekit Artifact]

When I rotate the view to look around I notice a black artifact which resembles a low poly sphere in the background. Turning shadows on and off doesn't fix it, its as if there is an extraneous node in the scene, however I am sure that there is not. Its probably some sort of lighting issue, but Im not sure. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: It may be that the background node (inverted sphere) is clipping with zFar, but Im not sure 100%.